# xcode 8 UIStackView. How to make round buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using `UIStackView` and I am trying to make the buttons round. My first four buttons have user defined runtime attributes:

```
layer.cornerRadius Number 10  
layer.masksToBounds Boolean true
```

[image]

Comment: Check if those values are really set as you expect. Put a breakpoint in viewDidAppear and print "po button.layer.cornerRadius" in console. What do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why your attempt to use user-defined runtime attributes is not working; it's a legitimate technique, and I've used it.

That said, here's another approach: use a UIButton subclass. Define your subclass to set these values in its initializer (here, `init(coder:)` is what you'll need to implement). Then, in the storyboard, use the Identity inspector to make these buttons instances of this subclass.

This is actually a *better* approach than yours, because it encapsulates in *one* place what *all* the buttons have in common. Having to define the *same* attributes for *four buttons separately* was always a Bad Smell!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using images you could create a circle image of the size you need it to be. Then, assuming it's a UIButton, you can add it as a backgroundImage.

**Storyboards**
[Xcode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TASzg.png)

**Swift 3**

```
let circle = UIImage(named: "circle")
button.setBackgroundImage(circle, for: UIControlState.normal)
```